# How JMeter runs its threads

Tags: jmeter

I wonder how threads are implemented in JMeter. For example, I have 10 threads (users). Loop count is 50. So every thread will run 50 tests. Does every thread run 50 tests independently on other threads or JMeter runs first loop, waits for slowest thread, then runs second loop, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where you have a ramp period. If you have that defined, it'll stagger the start of each thread by the defined number of seconds. If it waits for all previous loop threads to complete before iterating the next loop, you should see a definite hump in your loading.

In my experience this does not happen. This is strong evidence that each thread does 50 iterations regardless of the state of the other threads.